# Make a URL that redirects to your last opened IE page?

Tags: url, internet-explorer

A URL link that will redirect your browser to your last opened internet page.

How could this be made possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can code that can link to the last opened internet page.

If it is the same browser session you can call [`history.back()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/back)